# Create Action Doesn't Insert - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a profile that is associated with a member id based on Devise authentication.

When creating the profile, the values aren't inserted into the database.

Routes file.

```
  resources :troopers do
     resource :trooper_profile
  end
```

Trooper model

```
has_one :trooper_profile
```

Trooper Profile model

```
belongs_to :trooper
```

Trooper Controller #create action

```
  def create
 @trooper = current_trooper
 @profile = @trooper.build_trooper_profile(params[:profile])  
 respond_to do |format|
   if @profile.save
     format.html { redirect_to(trooper_trooper_profile_path, :notice => 'Profile was successfully created.') }
   else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
   end
 end
```

end

Profile Form

```
<%= form_for @profile, :url => trooper_trooper_profile_path(@trooper) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :first_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name %><br /><br />
<%= f.label :last_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :last_name %><br /><br />
<p><%= submit_tag "Create Profile" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Server output

```
Started POST "/troopers/1/trooper_profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-20 13:04:01 +1000
Processing by TrooperProfilesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LhT6b4xu5bIJ5kwhS74L7dpaGbuR5BTdirh9AziD+Ew=", "trooper_profile"=>{"first_name"=>"Robert", "last_name"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Profile", "trooper_id"=>"1"}
Trooper Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "troopers".* FROM "troopers" WHERE ("troopers"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
TrooperProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "trooper_profiles".* FROM "trooper_profiles" WHERE ("trooper_profiles".trooper_id = 1) LIMIT 1
Rendered trooper_profiles/_form.html.erb (11.7ms)
Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered shared/_menutop.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered trooper_profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 22.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

I've got this same setup in another application and can't see why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following...

```
@profile = @trooper.build_trooper_profile(params[:trooper_profile])
```

It appears the parameters being passed are :trooper_profile

```
trooper_profile"=>{"first_name"=>"Robert", "last_name"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Profile", "trooper_id"=>"1"}
```

However, you're referencing :profile

Comment: I don't always understand all the bits of rails but your answer means I'll know for next time. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help.  One thing that would DRY it up a bit is to change TrooperProfile model to Profile.  You're already noticing the redundancies (e.g. trooper_trooper_profile_path, trooper.trooper_profile)  Whereas if it were Profile, it begins to read like a rails app.  (trooper.profile, trooper_profile_path, etc).  Understanding you know your app better than I do and realizing this wasn't your question... take it with the grain of salt it deserves...

Answer (score 0):

If it's rendering the `new` view, then the profile isn't saving - perhaps it's a validation error? Does TrooperProfile require a last name (blank in your example)?